# store the values to a variable after executing the template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

This cloudformation template is working as expected:

https://github.com/shantanuo/cloudformation/blob/master/updated/esbck.yml

But how do I output the ARN of IAM role that it creates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Marcins answer, if you export the output, it becomes available for use in other Cloudformation templates deployed in the same AWS account (in the same region)

Add an export to the output:

```yaml
Outputs:
  RoleArn:
    Value: !GetAtt EsSnapshotRole.Arn
    Export:
      Name: EsSnapshotRoleArn
```

Once this is done, you can use the [`Fn::ImportValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) intrinsic function in other templates

```yaml
# some-other-template.yml

Resources:
  SomeResourceRequiringRoleArn:
    Type: AWS::SomeService::SomeResource
    Properties:
      IamRoleArn: !ImportValue EsSnapshotRoleArn
```

Answer (score 1):

Have to add [output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) section:

```
Outputs:

  RoleArn:
     Value: !GetAtt EsSnapshotRole.Arn
```